# Using a trigger to update a DateTime value based on two non-DateTime values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, triggers, data-conversion

Some background:

I am currently working with a SQL Server database-driven application which contains audit tables, which are automatically updated based on certain actions performed by users. We have had a feature request to add additional information to these audit tables in the form of a `DateTime`. The issue lies around the fact that the source data for the required datetime object only exists as two string values (one for date, and one for time) which are stored in an 'object attributes' table (which we cannot modify, as it forms a core part of our software stack) in the form of key-value pairs. The 'attributes table' containing the information looks a little like this:

```
| Foreign_Key (uniqueidentifier) |  Data_Key (nvarchar) | Data_Value (nvarchar) |
|             {guid 1}           |        'Date'        |       '10/11/12'      |
|             {guid 1}           |        'Time'        |         '1315'        |
|             {guid 2}           |        'Date'        |       '11/12/13'      |
|             {guid 2}           |        'Time'        |         '1416'        |
```

What we are trying to achieve is to insert a pure `DateTime` value into the audit table (which, for the purposes of this question, we can modify), based on the above data. The ideal output for this would be:

```
| Primary_Key (uniqueidentifier) |     DateT_Value (datetime)   |
|            {guid 1}            |       10/11/12 13:15:00      | 
|            {guid 2}            |       11/12/13 14:16:00      |
```

To enforce this, I have written the following SQL Server trigger for the source table which should create a `DateTime` value based on the two string values stored in the attributes table, according to the ID of the object in question:

```
DECLARE @DateFormat INT
SET @DateFormat = -- Subquery to retrieve date format ID - removed for clarity

UPDATE AuditTable
SET DateT_Value = 
    DATEADD (minute,
            (CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(
                    (SELECT Data_Value  
                     FROM inserted
                     WHERE inserted.Data_Key = 'Time'
                     AND inserted.Foreign_Key = AuditTable.Primary_Key)
                     , 3, 2)) + ((CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(
                                    (SELECT Data_Value  
                                     FROM inserted
                                     WHERE inserted.Data_Key = 'Time'
                                     AND inserted.Foreign_Key = AuditTable.Primary_Key),
                                1, 2))) * 60)),
             CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                        (SELECT Data_Value
                         FROM inserted
                         WHERE inserted.Data_Key = 'Date'
                         AND inserted.Foreign_Key = AuditTable.Primary_Key),
                     @DateFormat))
FROM AuditTable
INNER JOIN inserted
ON inserted.Foreign_Key = AuditTable.Primary_Key
```

Now, when I try and run this query stand-alone (removing references to 'inserted' and replacing the in-memory table with an instance of the real table that it would be referencing), it works fine - the DateT_Value fields are populated for all rows in the audit table, as expected.

However, when this logic is placed in a trigger and I attempt to use the 'inserted' table (which should, in theory, contain all the rows which are being added to the 'source' table), I get a NULL value being inserted into the DateTime field of the 'audit' table.

I can only assume that for whatever reason the 'inserted' table does not return any rows to the outer update statement - however given that I am joining based on an ID (which is known to be unique) and field names on the source table within the conversion logic (which, in this case, will never contain more than one instance of data for a particular field) I would assume that would be enough?

It's also worth noting that I have tried removing the complex date conversion logic from the trigger and replacing it with a simple

```
UPDATE AuditTable
SET DateValue = GETDATE() -- Fake date
FROM AuditTable
INNER JOIN inserted
ON inserted.Foreign_Key = AuditTable.Primary_Key
```

for debugging purposes - yet I still see the same behaviour.

Is there something around the behaviour of the 'inserted' table that I am missing?

Cheers.

Comment: Does the application always insert both rows as part of a single `INSERT` statement? Because if not, you'll always have one row but not the other when the trigger fires for each separate insert.

Comment: I will double check this, but I believe that yes, both rows are always inserted within the same statement.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is does the application do `INSERT (...) VALUES (...); INSERT (...) VALUES (...);` (in which case the trigger fires twice) or does it do `INSERT (...) VALUES (...),(...)`. Your trigger assumes the second (or moral equivalent)

Comment: @jpw: The trigger is on the attributes table - something I should have mentioned is that we have two triggers on this table (one for insert, one for update), however the logic for each is pretty much identical. The contents of the audit table are initially populated by a different trigger in the system - we can safely assume that (some) data exists in the audit table by the time we get to this point.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @jpw: SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It is about timing. When you use trigger, it has not yet reflected to db. And in that transaction you try to get value and try to join, but the value is not yet created in trigger. Split the query, first insert, then update